# $.ajax does not work in Android browser (Android 2.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I got this piece of code that uses Websocket implementation. Everytime it receives an incoming request, it updates the `stage``div`. I tested it in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox and it works fine. However when I tested in Android browser, it didnt worked, `stage div` was not updated.

```
socket.handlers.myhandler = function(o){
    var data = o[0];
    console.log(o);
    if(data.code == "CLIENT"){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "",
                context: $("#stage"),
                success: function(s,x){
                $(this).html(s);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Note:** The Android browser receives the incoming request, because it successfully logs the `o` variable and its data.code is equal to CLIENT. Im using Android 2.2.

**Console Output:**

```
[Object {code="CLIENT", data=Object, status="OK"}]
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I think this is working. What is the contents of `o.data`?

Comment: Its working in Chrome and Mozilla but not in Android 2.2.